# find common lines between multiple files

Tags: text-processing, files

I have 4 files which are like

```
       file A
       >TCONS_00000867
       >TCONS_00001442
       >TCONS_00001447
       >TCONS_00001528
       >TCONS_00001529
       >TCONS_00001668
       >TCONS_00001921

       file b
       >TCONS_00001528
       >TCONS_00001529
       >TCONS_00001668
       >TCONS_00001921
       >TCONS_00001922
       >TCONS_00001924

       file c
       >TCONS_00001529
       >TCONS_00001668
       >TCONS_00001921
       >TCONS_00001922
       >TCONS_00001924
       >TCONS_00001956
       >TCONS_00002048

       file d
       >TCONS_00001922
       >TCONS_00001924
       >TCONS_00001956
       >TCONS_00002048
```

All files contain more than 2000 lines and are sorted by first column.

I want to find common lines in all files. I tried awk and grep and comm but not working.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the files are already sorted:

```
comm -12 a b |
  comm -12 - c |
  comm -12 - d
```

`comm` finds `comm`on lines between files. By default `comm` prints 3 TAB-separated columns:

1. The lines unique to the first file,
2. The lines unique to the second file,
3. The lines common to both files.

With the `-1`, `-2`, `-3` options, we suppress the corresponding column. So `comm -12 a b` reports the lines common to `a` and `b`. `-` can be used in place of a file name to mean stdin.

Answer (score 7):

```
cat a b c d |sort |uniq -c |sed -n -e 's/^ *4 \(.*\)/\1/p'
```

Comment: Actually, save the `sed`, this is quite good for finding duplicate lines across many files: `cat` to `sort` to `uniq -c`. Somehow I didn't quite think of this, good answer!

Comment: You can also use uniq command to only print duplicated lines: `uniq -cd`

Answer (score 0):

`comm` would be cool if it took 3+ files as input.  Since it doesn't I don't see the value in it, and would recommend just using `grep`:

- Doesn't require pre-sorted input
- Don't have to suppress output columns
- Command is just as short and easy as `comm`

```
grep -f a.txt b.txt | 
  grep -f - c.txt |
  grep -f - d.txt
```

`-f <file>` tells grep to look in `<file>` for patterns, so any line in `a.txt` also found in `b.txt` will be output as a match.  This continues down the pipeline, so lines found in both `a.txt` AND `b.txt` will be used as patterns to match in `c.txt`.  At the end of the pipeline the only output shown are lines which appear in every file.

Comment: This requires comparing ***every*** line in `a.txt` to ***every*** line in `b.txt`.  If each file has 1000 lines, that's (theoretically) a million comparisons.  That's the value of `comm` — if `a` line 6 sorts between `b` line 8 and line 9, you don't have to compare it to lines 10, 11, 12, ...

Comment: Good point, if `comm` actually moves on to the next pattern after finding the first match, then it is more efficient than `grep`.  However a test indicates that `comm` is only slightly faster
```
$ time comm -12  <(seq 1 1000) <(seq 1 1000) | comm -12 - <(seq 1 1000) | comm -12 - <(seq 1 1000) | comm -12 - <(seq 1 1000) | tail -1
1000

real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.010s
$ time grep -f <(seq 1 1000) <(seq 1 1000) | grep -f - <(seq 1 1000) |  grep -f - <(seq 1 1000) |  grep -f - <(seq 1 1000) | tail -1
1000

real    0m0.053s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %h;  for dir(test => / file \w /) {   \
               %h{$_}++ for .lines.unique };         \
            .put if .value == 4 for %h;'

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my %h; my @a = dir(test => / file \w /);  \
            for @a { %h{$_}++ for .lines.unique };    \
            for %h { .put if .value == @a.elems };'
```

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, Raku's `dir` function is used to inspect the local directory and pull out regex matches to filenames. Here we assume the files are named `file` followed by `\w` a word character, but it's equally easy to (let's say) match `\.txt` files with the appropriate regex (not globbing pattern).

For both answers above a `%h` hash is declared. Once filenames are obtained (actually `.IO` objects), they are iterated through `line`wise using `for`, incrementing the hash key every time an identical line is seen.

In the first answer (last statement) the lines are returned if their `value` matches `4`, i.e. from all four input files.  In the second answer (last statement) the lines are returned if their `value` matches `@a.elems`, i.e. the number of input files (in other words--this value is set dynamically).

Sample Input  (Note: files are named `fileA`, `fileB`, etc.  Also,  `fileA` has an extra line at the end, compared to OP's first file):

```
       fileA
       >TCONS_00000867
       >TCONS_00001442
       >TCONS_00001447
       >TCONS_00001528
       >TCONS_00001529
       >TCONS_00001668
       >TCONS_00001921
       >TCONS_00001922

       fileB
       >TCONS_00001528
       >TCONS_00001529
       >TCONS_00001668
       >TCONS_00001921
       >TCONS_00001922
       >TCONS_00001924

       fileC
       >TCONS_00001529
       >TCONS_00001668
       >TCONS_00001921
       >TCONS_00001922
       >TCONS_00001924
       >TCONS_00001956
       >TCONS_00002048

       fileD
       >TCONS_00001922
       >TCONS_00001924
       >TCONS_00001956
       >TCONS_00002048
```

Sample Output (showing all key/value counts):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %h; for dir(test => / file \w /) { %h{$_}++ for .lines.unique }; .say for %h.sort: -*.value;'
>TCONS_00001922 => 4
>TCONS_00001668 => 3
>TCONS_00001921 => 3
>TCONS_00001924 => 3
>TCONS_00001529 => 3
>TCONS_00002048 => 2
>TCONS_00001528 => 2
>TCONS_00001956 => 2
>TCONS_00000867 => 1
>TCONS_00001442 => 1
>TCONS_00001447 => 1
```

Sample Output (showing only lines where `.value == 4` or `.value == @a.elems`):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %h; my @a = dir(test => / file \w /); for @a { %h{$_}++ for .lines.unique }; for %h { .key.put if .value == @a.elems};'
>TCONS_00001922
```

---

Finally, for those who prefer shell-globbing, Raku can do this as well. The key is remembering that the `$*ARGFILES` dynamic variable must be converted to `.handles` to read the input properly:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my ($n,%h); for $*ARGFILES.handles -> $fh { $n++; %h{$_}++ for $fh.lines.unique }; for %h { .key.put if .value == $n };' file?
>TCONS_00001922
```

---

*NOTE: The OP's test input seems like a trick question because no lines are in common between all four files! Thus the first file (`fileA`) has been modified to provide a positive control: `>TCONS_00001922`.*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774047/7270649
https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org