# How to find the intersection of multiple files (not necessarily two files)?

Tags: shell-script, comm

I'd like to write a simple script for finding the intersection of **multiple files** (the common lines among all files), so after reading some here ([link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191924/find-common-lines-between-multiple-files)) i tried to write a bash script, which unfortunately fails for me. 
what am i doing wrong?

```
RES=$(comm -12 ${1}  ${2})

for FILE in ${@:3}
do
    RES=$(comm -12 $FILE  ${RES})
done
```

Is there is any other suggestion how to implement this perhaps with `parallel` or `xargs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dereference `RES` in:

```
comm $FILE  ${RES}
```

the content of `RES` replaces `${RES}`. But `comm` expects a filename as argument, so for instance if `$RES` contains `hello` `comm` tries to open a file named `hello`.

Instead you could use a temporary file to store the common lines during the process:

```
tmp=$(mktemp --tmpdir)
tmp2=$(mktemp --tmpdir)
comm -12 ${1}  ${2} >$tmp

for FILE in ${@:3}
do
    comm -12 $FILE  $tmp >$tmp2
    rm $tmp 
    mv $tmp2 $tmp   
done

cat $tmp 
rm $tmp
```

Comment: Erwan thank you for the well written answer and explanation!

Answer (score 2):

A function allows for a recursive approach

```
f() {
     if (($# == 1))
     then
         cat $1;
         return;
     fi
     comm -12 $1 <(f "${@:2}")
}

f file1 file2 file3 file4 file5...
```

Answer (score 1):

No `parallel` nor `xargs`, nor `comm` necessary. Try a function

```
$ intersection() {  sort $@ | uniq -c | sed -n "s/^ *$# //p"; }
$ intersection file[1-3]
line2
line4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `comm` wants two files, and `$RES` is a variable.

But we can *cheat* and make it look like a file by use of process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

RES=$(comm -12 ${1}  ${2})

for FILE in ${@:3}
do
    RES="$(comm -12 $FILE  <(printf %s "${RES}"))"
done

printf %s "$RES"
```

You can see this is pretty much the same as your original, but we use a `<(...)` structure to run a command and use that as a file name.

So if we have these three files:

```
a:line1
a:line2
a:line3
a:line4
b:line2
b:line4
b:line6
c:line2
c:line4
c:line8
```

We can compare them:

```
% ./allcomp a b c
line2
line4
```